# Bash Prompt Loses Characters

Tags: linux, bash, prompt

After writing a new prompt for Bash, I noticed that one character of my commands were being lost when it wrapped to the new line. Here is an image of the example (I typed `1234567890` over and over):

[image: prompt]

Here is my `$PS1`

```
PS1="\n   [\[\e[0;90m\]\d \t\[\e[0m\]] [\[\e[0;90m\]\$(/bin/ls -1 | /usr/bin/wc -l | /bin/sed 's: ::g') files, \$(/usr/bin/du -sh | cut -f1)\[\e[0m]\n[\[\e[0;36m\]\#\[\e[0m]\] \[\e[0;95m\]\u\[\e[0;90m\]@\[\e[1;92m\]\h\[\e[0m\]: \[\e[1;34m\]\w \[\e[1;30m\]\$\[\e[0m\] "
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What's this bit for `\[\e[0m]\]`?  Is the `]` supposed to be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's this bit for `\[\e[0m]\]`?

Is the `]` after the `m` supposed to be there?

Comment: You fixed it! The first `]` needed to go at the end (to become `\[\e[0m\]]`). Thanks!